# 7z zipping directory relatively

Tags: windows, path, 7zip

I am trying to use 7z to zip a directory so I do

```
C:/7z a -tzip mydirectory/testing.zip mydirectory/testing -o* -r
```

The problem the outputted zip file has for the content the entire directory structure path

```
mydirectory/testing/....
```

But I want the files under testing to be zipped and not have any paths above reflected in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the directory to `mydirectory/testing` first and use `*` to get all the files.

```
cd mydirectory\testing
C:\7z.exe a -tzip ../testing.zip * -r
```